# Shadow in UIView cannot overlay Entry or Editor or Picker in Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, effects, dropshadow

I added an RoutingEffect in Xamarin Form project and PlatformEffect in my Xamarin.iOS project. It will add effect to Stacklayout. The Stacklayout in this demo is a custom navigation bar. The below of navigation bar is a scrollview has many cells (label, entry, picker).

I implemented in Android is OK.
But in iOS has problem: Shadow effect cannot overlays some controls, such as: Entry, Editor, Picker. Could you share me how to fix it?
This is code in Xamarin.iOS project.

```
public class DropShadowEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        try
        {
            var effect = (myDemo.UIControls.DropShadowEffect)Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is myDemo.UIControls.DropShadowEffect);

            if (effect != null)
            {
                Container.Layer.CornerRadius = effect.Radius;
                Container.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;// effect.Color.ToCGColor();
                Container.Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(effect.DistanceX, effect.DistanceY);
                Container.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 0.8f;
                Container.Layer.ShadowRadius = 2f;
                Container.Layer.ShouldRasterize = true;
                Container.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot set property on attached control. Error: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

*Shadow effect overly Label is OK

[image: Shadow effect overly Label is OK]

*Shadow effect cannot overlay either Picker or Entry

[image: cannot overlay either Picker or Entry]

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

Actually, such as `Label` will still overlay the shadow.But it doesn't seem obvious.If you set the background of label (such as red ),you will see the overlay.

**Solution:**

You can set the `BackgroundColor` of the `Picker` and `Entry` in the custom renderer to let the alpha as 0.

For example in `EntryRenderer`

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.BackgroundColor = new UIColor(1,1,1,0);//The last parameter sets the alpha of backgound as transparent
            Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            Control.Layer.CornerRadius = xxx;  //set the rounded corner
            Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.xxx.CGColor;
            Control.Layer.BorderWidth = xxx;           
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this solution, but I cannot set background color of either entry or picker. It is always transparent. Do you have any other solutions?

Comment: Why you can not set it?

Comment: Because I set alpha 0 to BackgroundColor which is transparent.
If I don't set alpha 0, problem about shadow is exist.

  private void SetBackgroundColor()
  {
   Control.BackgroundColor = new UIColor(
    (nfloat)FormElement.BackgroundColor.R,
    (nfloat)FormElement.BackgroundColor.G,
    (nfloat)FormElement.BackgroundColor.B,
    0);
  }